# Why is UITextView contentInset/padding different on simulator vs device?

Tags: ios, layout, uitextview, padding

I'm debugging a strange text wrapping problem on my device that I have tracked down to some kind of modification in the `UITextView` contentInset value starting in XCode 4.

Here is the sample code I am using to showcase this bug:

```
NSString *message = @"How are you doing?";
CGSize messageDimensions = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,9999)
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGFloat xOffset = 20;
CGFloat yOffset = 20;

CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, messageDimensions.width+16, messageDimensions.height+16);

self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame] autorelease];
self.textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
self.textView.text = message;
self.textView.editable = NO;

[self.view addSubview:self.textView];
```

Attached are two screenshots running code on the iOS 5 simulator and on my iPhone 4.

Here is the iPhone 4 running iOS5:

[image: device]

Here is the simulator running iOS5.0:

[image: simulator]

As you can see, it is wrapping in one but not the other. In order to prevent wrapping on my iOS4 device I have to change this line:

```
CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, messageDimensions.width+16, messageDimensions.height+16);
```

To have a padding of +17 not +16.

Can anyone tell me if this is a known bug, and if the `UITextView` padding amount is a constant value somewhere in UIKit to which I can refer instead of hard-coding it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry my mistake - I am running simulator 5.0, not 5.1. I will correct in the body of the post.